# Symfony - Heroku deployment get Error 500

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, doctrine, http-status-code-500

I try to deploy my first app in Symfony 5 with Heroku and sadly ... I got an error (500) :'(

My configs var are set on **APP_ENV=prod**

There is my heroku logs if you can help me :

```
2021-01-25T00:38:59.425242+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(183): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->preBoot()
2021-01-25T00:38:59.425426+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 /app/public/index.php(20): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle()
2021-01-25T00:38:59.425473+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 {main}
2021-01-25T00:38:59.425749+00:00 app[web.1]: thrown in /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php on line 227
2021-01-25T00:38:59.426268+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.37.207.144 - - [25/Jan/2021:00:38:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
2021-01-25T00:41:26.188495+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=whispering-tundra-20205.herokuapp.com request_id=e1ef779b-2c35-42eb-92e5-48ef7f683861 fwd="91.169.120.60" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=52ms status=500 bytes=169 protocol=https
2021-01-25T00:41:26.189405+00:00 app[web.1]: [25-Jan-2021 00:41:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Specified non-existing directory "/app/src/Entity" as Doctrine mapping source. in /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php:227
2021-01-25T00:41:26.189419+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2021-01-25T00:41:26.189765+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php(93): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\AbstractDoctrineExtension->assertValidMappingConfiguration()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.190187+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(650): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\AbstractDoctrineExtension->loadMappingInformation()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.190645+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(480): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->loadOrmEntityManagerMappingInformation()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.191027+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(433): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->loadOrmEntityManager()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.191311+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(75): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->ormLoad()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.191598+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(76): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->load()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.191950+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(39): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.192333+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/Compiler.php(91): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.192680+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(736): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.192938+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(541): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.193250+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(780): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.193485+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(183): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->preBoot()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.193670+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 /app/public/index.php(20): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle()
2021-01-25T00:41:26.193702+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 {main}
2021-01-25T00:41:26.193972+00:00 app[web.1]: thrown in /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php on line 227
2021-01-25T00:41:26.194500+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.152.193.4 - - [25/Jan/2021:00:41:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
2021-01-25T00:55:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user **********
2021-01-25T00:55:17.961881+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f507c6d6 by user **********
2021-01-25T00:55:17.961881+00:00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user **********
2021-01-25T00:55:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-01-25T00:55:18.346303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-01-25T00:55:18.348187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-01-25T00:55:20.567808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `heroku-php-apache2 public/`
2021-01-25T00:55:21.495994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-01-25T00:55:21.520995+00:00 app[web.1]: SIGTERM received, attempting graceful shutdown...
2021-01-25T00:55:21.521006+00:00 app[web.1]: Stopping php-fpm...
2021-01-25T00:55:21.521256+00:00 app[web.1]: Stopping httpd gracefully...
2021-01-25T00:55:21.526265+00:00 app[web.1]: Shutdown complete.
2021-01-25T00:55:21.601752+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-01-25T00:55:23.506483+00:00 app[web.1]: DOCUMENT_ROOT changed to 'public/'
2021-01-25T00:55:23.570954+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 536870912 Bytes of RAM
2021-01-25T00:55:23.602509+00:00 app[web.1]: PHP memory_limit is 128M Bytes
2021-01-25T00:55:23.612150+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting php-fpm with 4 workers...
2021-01-25T00:55:23.785370+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting httpd...
2021-01-25T00:55:24.359383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-25T00:55:27.733514+00:00 app[web.1]: [25-Jan-2021 00:55:27 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Specified non-existing directory "/app/src/Entity" as Doctrine mapping source. in /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php:227
2021-01-25T00:55:27.733538+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2021-01-25T00:55:27.733938+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php(93): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\AbstractDoctrineExtension->assertValidMappingConfiguration()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.734227+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=whispering-tundra-20205.herokuapp.com request_id=ac189f6f-70c7-4838-8e0c-bd622ea91eff fwd="my-ip-adress" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=349ms status=500 bytes=169 protocol=https
2021-01-25T00:55:27.734280+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(650): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\AbstractDoctrineExtension->loadMappingInformation()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.734614+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(480): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->loadOrmEntityManagerMappingInformation()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.734925+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(433): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->loadOrmEntityManager()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.735217+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(75): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->ormLoad()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.735522+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(76): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->load()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.735846+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(39): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.736118+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/Compiler.php(91): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.736360+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(736): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.736565+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(541): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.736757+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(780): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.736931+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(183): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->preBoot()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.737068+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 /app/public/index.php(20): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle()
2021-01-25T00:55:27.737092+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 {main}
2021-01-25T00:55:27.737283+00:00 app[web.1]: thrown in /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php on line 227
2021-01-25T00:55:27.737683+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.178.208 - - [25/Jan/2021:00:55:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
2021-01-25T00:55:51.444587+00:00 app[web.1]: [25-Jan-2021 00:55:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Specified non-existing directory "/app/src/Entity" as Doctrine mapping source. in /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php:227
2021-01-25T00:55:51.444604+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2021-01-25T00:55:51.444948+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php(93): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\AbstractDoctrineExtension->assertValidMappingConfiguration()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.445262+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(650): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\AbstractDoctrineExtension->loadMappingInformation()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.445404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=whispering-tundra-20205.herokuapp.com request_id=0049f601-35b2-49a8-b91b-302b76b5db81 fwd="91.169.120.60" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=55ms status=500 bytes=169 protocol=https
2021-01-25T00:55:51.445596+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(480): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->loadOrmEntityManagerMappingInformation()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.445909+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(433): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->loadOrmEntityManager()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.446191+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(75): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->ormLoad()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.446563+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(76): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->load()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.446898+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(39): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.447183+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/Compiler.php(91): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.447419+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(736): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.447639+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(541): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.447832+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(780): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.447997+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(183): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->preBoot()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.448135+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 /app/public/index.php(20): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle()
2021-01-25T00:55:51.448169+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 {main}
2021-01-25T00:55:51.448358+00:00 app[web.1]: thrown in /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php on line 227
2021-01-25T00:55:51.448708+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.178.208 - - [25/Jan/2021:00:55:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
2021-01-25T00:59:08.222099+00:00 app[web.1]: [25-Jan-2021 00:59:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Specified non-existing directory "/app/src/Entity" as Doctrine mapping source. in /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php:227
2021-01-25T00:59:08.222120+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2021-01-25T00:59:08.222340+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=whispering-tundra-20205.herokuapp.com request_id=005dddf7-4ba2-487d-8580-d41263505496 fwd="91.169.120.60" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=50ms status=500 bytes=169 protocol=https
2021-01-25T00:59:08.222567+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php(93): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\AbstractDoctrineExtension->assertValidMappingConfiguration()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.222996+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(650): Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DependencyInjection\AbstractDoctrineExtension->loadMappingInformation()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.223437+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(480): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->loadOrmEntityManagerMappingInformation()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.223834+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(433): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->loadOrmEntityManager()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.224207+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 /app/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php(75): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->ormLoad()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.224590+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(76): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension->load()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.225004+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(39): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.225367+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/Compiler.php(91): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.225680+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 /app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(736): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.225950+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(541): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.226208+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(780): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.226446+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(183): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->preBoot()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.226641+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 /app/public/index.php(20): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle()
2021-01-25T00:59:08.226669+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 {main}
2021-01-25T00:59:08.226923+00:00 app[web.1]: thrown in /app/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php on line 227
2021-01-25T00:59:08.227418+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.183.55 - - [25/Jan/2021:00:59:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
```

I think there is a problem with AbstractDoctrineExtension.php at line 227 but don't know what i must do and i'm not sure that's the problem ...

I also create my Procfile before deployment with this line :

```
web: heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Comment: _"Specified non-existing directory "/app/src/Entity as Doctrine Mapping Source"_. Reading the error log is usually very helpful. Check your doctrine configuration, and your existing directories.

Comment: thank you for pointing that, so i try to create a new directory "Entity" in the src folder, i push the changes and nothing changes (sorry if i did something wrong, i'm not an expert at all :p)

Answer (score -1):

Did you do  composer require symfony/apache-pack ?

Comment: Yes i did it yesterday and it still don't work